# Can't create many modals

Tags: javascript

Ok, so here's the problem. I have a simple structure for a modal as follows:

HTML:

```
    <div class = "wrapper">
        <img src = "conselhoantoniobrennand.png">
        <div class = "overlay">
            <div class = "content">
                <h2> Antônio Brenannd </h2> 
                <a id = "modalBtn" class = "button"> Saiba mais </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div id = "simplemodal" class = "modal">
        <div class = "modal-content">
            <div class = "modal-header">
                <span class = "closeBtn"> &times; </span>
                <h1 style = "color: #ffffff; margin: 0;"> Antônio Brennand </h1>
            </div>
            <div class = "modal-body">
                <p> <span class = "nome"> Simple text  </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('simplemodal');
var modalBtn = document.getElementById('modalBtn'); 
var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtn')[0];

modalBtn.addEventListener("click", openModal);
closeBtn.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
window.addEventListener("click", clickOutside);


function openModal(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal(){
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

function clickOutside(e){
    if(e.target == modal){
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine when I have only one modal on the webpage. However, I need to have 13 modals like this one. What I try to do is something like this:

HTML:

```
    <div class = "wrapper">
        <img src = "conselhoantoniobrennand.png">
        <div class = "overlay">
            <div class = "content">
                <h2> Antônio Brenannd </h2> 
                <a id = "modalBtnbrennand" class = "button"> Saiba mais </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div id = "simplemodalbrennand" class = "modal">
        <div class = "modal-content">
            <div class = "modal-header">
                <span class = "closeBtnbrennand"> &times; </span>
                <h1 style = "color: #ffffff; margin: 0;"> Antônio Brennand </h1>
            </div>
            <div class = "modal-body">
                <p> <span class = "nome"> Antônio Brennand </span> é sócio da Brennand Energia.  </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
var modalbrennand = document.getElementById('simplemodalbrennand');
var modalBtnbrennand = document.getElementById('modalBtnbrennand'); 
var closeBtnbrennand = document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtnbrennand')[0];

modalBtnbrennand.addEventListener("click", openModal);
closeBtnbrennand.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
window.addEventListener("click", clickOutside);


function openModal(){
    modalbrennand.style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal(){
    modalbrennand.style.display = "none";
}

function clickOutside(e){
    if(e.target == modal){
        modalbrennand.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

So I basically try to customize the tag that are caught on the JS code in order to have 13 modals. Due to this strategy, I have 13 javascript "code blocks" in which the only difference is the name of the variables. The same is true for HTML: except for the modal content (which is obviously different), the only difference in the code is the name of the id's of the tags that are going to be called on JS.

The problem is: when I have all the 13 modals in the page (when all the 13 buttons are set), every button that I click calls the same modal. I am not being able to call the 13 different modals. What am I doing wrong?

I tried to be very specific, but if I'm doing something wrong in the way I'm imputing this question, please clarify me.

Comment: Just using vanilla JS?

Comment: Make sure your IDs are unique

Comment: @Fallenreaper unfortunately I haven't learned yet to use JQuery or other javascript frameworks. I'm open to suggestions about what to learn on this language though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set unique id for each modal . I prefer to use `onclick` on element so you can use only one function with current `this` property. The important thing is to set `unique id`. I provide some example here with `onclick` and `unique id` ....

```js
window.addEventListener("click", clickOutside);

function openModal(self) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var modal = document.getElementById(self.id + "_modal");
    modal.style.display = 'block';
}

function closeModal(id){
   event.stopPropagation();
   var modal = document.getElementById(id + "_modal");
    modal.style.display = 'none';
}

function clickOutside(e){
    var modal = document.querySelectorAll('.modal')
    for(var i = 0; i < modal.length;i++) {
        if(!modal[i].contains(e.target)){
           modal[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.modal {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class = "wrapper">
        <img src = "conselhoantoniobrennand.png">
        <div class = "overlay">
            <div class = "content">
                <h2> Antônio Brenannd </h2> 
                <a id="simple" class ="button" onclick="openModal(this)"> Saiba mais </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div id="simple_modal" class = "modal">
        <div class = "modal-content">
            <div class = "modal-header">
                <span class = "closeBtn" onclick="closeModal('simple')"> &times; </span>
                <h1 style = "color: #ffffff; margin: 0;"> Antônio Brennand </h1>
            </div>
            <div class = "modal-body">
                <p> <span class = "nome"> Simple text  </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "wrapper">
        <img src = "conselhoantoniobrennand.png">
        <div class = "overlay">
            <div class = "content">
                <h2> Antônio Brenannd </h2> 
                <a id="brennand" class ="button" onclick="openModal(this)"> Saiba mais </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div id="brennand_modal" class="modal">
        <div class = "modal-content">
            <div class = "modal-header">
                <span class = "closeBtnbrennand" onclick="closeModal('brennand')"> &times; </span>
                <h1 style = "color: #ffffff; margin: 0;"> Antônio Brennand </h1>
            </div>
            <div class = "modal-body">
                <p> <span class = "nome"> Antônio Brennand </span> é sócio da Brennand Energia.  </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how to reuse the javascript code for more than one dialog with the same structure without having to repeat in code blocks. Pay attention on how to use an id pattern in html elements for dynamically adding the corresponding listeners to each modal.

**Run Code Snippet** to see the results.

```js
function getOpenModal(el){
    return function(){
     el.style.display = "block";
    }
}

function getCloseModal(el){
    return function(){
        el.style.display = "none";
    }
}

var modalBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('modalBtn');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(modalBtns, function(el) {
    var variable_id = el.id.split('_')[1];
    var simpleModal = document.getElementById('simplemodal_' + variable_id);
    el.addEventListener("click", getOpenModal(simpleModal));   
    
    var closeBtn = document.getElementById('closeBtn_' + variable_id);    
    closeBtn.addEventListener("click", getCloseModal(simpleModal));
});
```

```css
.modal {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class = "wrapper">
        <!--<img src = "conselho_antonio_brennand.png">-->
        <div class = "overlay">
            <div class = "content">
                <h2> Antônio Brenannd </h2> 
                <a class = "modalBtn" id="modalBtn_brennand" class = "button"> Saiba mais </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div id = "simplemodal_brennand" class = "modal">
        <div class = "modal-content">
            <div class = "modal-header">
                <span class = "closeBtn" id="closeBtn_brennand"> &times; </span>
                <h1 style = "color: #ffffff; margin: 0;"> Antônio Brennand </h1>
            </div>
            <div class = "modal-body">
                <p> <span class = "nome"> Antônio Brennand </span> é sócio da Brennand Energia.  </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
     <div class = "wrapper">
        <!--<img src = "conselho_antonio_lopes.png">-->
        <div class = "overlay">
            <div class = "content">
                <h2> Ricardo Lopes </h2> 
                <a class = "modalBtn" id="modalBtn_lopes" class = "button"> Saiba mais </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div id = "simplemodal_lopes" class = "modal">
        <div class = "modal-content">
            <div class = "modal-header">
                <span class = "closeBtn" id="closeBtn_lopes"> &times; </span>
                <h1 style = "color: #ffffff; margin: 0;"> Ricardo Lopes </h1>
            </div>
            <div class = "modal-body">
                <p> <span class = "nome"> Ricardo Lopes </span> é sócio da Brennand Energia.  </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my code, basically it re-uses the js code, so you don't have to write 13 part same code with different ids.

so each button for open modal, it needs a unique id, which can be like 'uniqueButtonId1' and 'uniqueButtonId2' etc, and for the close modal id you can just add the suffix like 'Target' or '_modal', it will be easy for JS to find the modal.

you still need to generate the 13 buttons and 13 modals, but JS code will be much tidy.

```js
var openModalBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
for (var i = 0; i < openModalBtns.length; i++) {
  openModalBtns[i].addEventListener('click', openModal);
}

var closeModalBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("closeBtnbrennand");
for (var i = 0; i < closeModalBtns.length; i++) {
  closeModalBtns[i].addEventListener('click', closeModal);
}


function openModal() {
  var openModalId = this.getAttribute('id') + 'Target';
  var modalToOpen = document.getElementById(openModalId);
  modalToOpen.style.display = 'block';
}

function closeModal() {
  this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.row {
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="conselhoantoniobrennand.png">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="content">
        <h2> Antônio Brenannd </h2>
        <a id="modalBtn1" class="button"> Saiba mais </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="modalBtn1Target" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="closeBtnbrennand"> &times; </span>
        <h1 style="color: #ffffff; margin: 0;"> Antônio Brennand </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p> <span class="nome"> Antônio Brennand </span> é sócio da Brennand Energia. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="conselhoantoniobrennand.png">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="content">
        <h2> Antônio Brenannd </h2>
        <a id="modalBtn2" class="button"> Saiba mais </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="modalBtn2Target" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="closeBtnbrennand"> &times; </span>
        <h1 style="color: #ffffff; margin: 0;"> Antônio Brennand </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p> <span class="nome"> Antônio Brennand </span> é sócio da Brennand Energia. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="conselhoantoniobrennand.png">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="content">
        <h2> Antônio Brenannd </h2>
        <a id="modalBtn3" class="button"> Saiba mais </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="modalBtn3Target" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="closeBtnbrennand"> &times; </span>
        <h1 style="color: #ffffff; margin: 0;"> Antônio Brennand </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p> <span class="nome"> Antônio Brennand </span> é sócio da Brennand Energia. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the [jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/fgu2r0nw/44/) you can check the example